# Windows 10-- Legacy Application cannot "see" system MAC address

Tags: windows-10, mac-address

I am attempting to run a legacy program (Agfa d-Workflow) which binds the software license to a MAC address. I am running Win10 but the program was originally written for Windows 2000. It is known to work under Windows 7.

The MAC address is hashed and used to verify a license key. I have obtained appropriate license for the MAC address assigned to my ethernet card and disabled all other network adapters-- but the software simply cannot "see" the MAC address and behaves as if there was no NIC at all.

I got the following from our vendor who provides very limited support: "it cannot be licensed on window 10 since 10 blocks access of apps to the MAC address of the NIC card, which is used for licensing."

I am looking for a possible workaround, or info on any known changes to the Windows API's between Windows 7 and Windows 10 which would affect the way applications access the hardware address of the NIC?

Comment: Run it within a VM. Sounds like the software is incompatible with modern security of Windows

Comment: Does running it elevated help?